# Can you adjust SQL query (outcome) based on conditions in table?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a (sub-)query and/or If statement in a MYSQL query. After Googling and searching, I **THINK** it should be possible with a CASE statement, but I am not sure.
My Questions are:

1: is it possible at all?

2: If it is: Could someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

**ISSUE:**
I have a table with PRODUCTS. Each PRODUCT can have a
-'in_stock' value of 0 or 1 (in stock NO or YES). 
-'status' with possible value of 'NULL' or 'DELETED'.
A product that has the status 'DELETED' can NOT be ordered, UNLESS in is in stock.

QUESTION
Is it possible to apply (some kind of) IF statement in a SQL query? Something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
WHERE
  CASE in_stock = 0
    THEN (AND status != 'DELETED')
    ELSE ()
```

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
    (in_stock = 0 AND status <> 'DELETED') OR
    in_stock > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND` and `OR` in a `WHERE` clause. The following query gives you all products that are either in stock or have not been deleted (or both):

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE in_stock = 1 OR status <> 'DELETED';
```

Another way of writing the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE NOT (in_stock = 0 AND status = 'DELETED');
```

You can have many conditions that you combine with `AND`, `OR`, and parentheses.